# Where can I find documentation for `assimilate_storage` function?

Tags: storage, primitive

[question originally posted on [polkadot forum](https://forum.polkadot.network/t/where-is-the-documentation-for-assimilate-storage-function/1667/1) but moved here since it seems to be considered a more appropriate place]

I do not find documentation for the [`assimilate_storage`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/search?p=1&q=assimilate_storage) function anywhere in the substrate codebase. It seems substrate documentation is provided in a Q&A style here on stackexchage ([ref](https://forum.polkadot.network/t/suggestion-add-support-and-bug-report-categories/1668)), that's why I'm asking it here.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

There is no documentation, substrate users should figure out what traits methods do by reading implementation and use cases.

Answer (score 1):

[answer originally posted by @alejandro on [polkadot forum](https://forum.polkadot.network/t/where-is-the-documentation-for-assimilate-storage-function/1667/2)]

`fn assimilate_storage` is part of [`BuildStorage`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/e9b0facf70eeb08032cc7e83548c62f0b4a24bb1/primitives/runtime/src/lib.rs#L185-L196) trait defined in primitives

```rust
/// Complex storage builder stuff.
#[cfg(feature = "std")]
pub trait BuildStorage {
    /// Build the storage out of this builder.
    fn build_storage(&self) -> Result<sp_core::storage::Storage, String> {
        let mut storage = Default::default();
        self.assimilate_storage(&mut storage)?;
        Ok(storage)
    }
    /// Assimilate the storage for this module into pre-existing overlays.
    fn assimilate_storage(&self, storage: &mut sp_core::storage::Storage) -> Result<(), String>;
}
```

You can find an [implementation for it in the chain_spec module](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/e9b0facf70eeb08032cc7e83548c62f0b4a24bb1/client/chain-spec/src/chain_spec.rs#L111-L134) in the client.

```rust
impl<G: RuntimeGenesis, E> BuildStorage for ChainSpec<G, E> {
    fn assimilate_storage(&self, storage: &mut Storage) -> Result<(), String> {
        match self.genesis.resolve()? {
            Genesis::Runtime(gc) => gc.assimilate_storage(storage),
            Genesis::Raw(RawGenesis { top: map, children_default: children_map }) => {
                storage.top.extend(map.into_iter().map(|(k, v)| (k.0, v.0)));
                children_map.into_iter().for_each(|(k, v)| {
                    let child_info = ChildInfo::new_default(k.0.as_slice());
                    storage
                        .children_default
                        .entry(k.0)
                        .or_insert_with(|| StorageChild { data: Default::default(), child_info })
                        .data
                        .extend(v.into_iter().map(|(k, v)| (k.0, v.0)));
                });
                Ok(())
            },
            // The `StateRootHash` variant exists as a way to keep note that other clients support
            // it, but Substrate itself isn't capable of loading chain specs with just a hash at the
            // moment.
            Genesis::StateRootHash(_) => Err("Genesis storage in hash format not supported".into()),
        }
    }
}
```

At the same time, `fn assimilate_storage` is part of the [trait `GenesisBuild` defined in `frame-support` pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/e9b0facf70eeb08032cc7e83548c62f0b4a24bb1/frame/support/src/traits/hooks.rs#L326-L348).

```rust
/// A trait to define the build function of a genesis config, T and I are placeholder for pallet
/// trait and pallet instance.
#[cfg(feature = "std")]
pub trait GenesisBuild<T, I = ()>: Default + sp_runtime::traits::MaybeSerializeDeserialize {
    /// The build function is called within an externalities allowing storage APIs.
    /// Thus one can write to storage using regular pallet storages.
    fn build(&self);

    /// Build the storage using `build` inside default storage.
    fn build_storage(&self) -> Result<sp_runtime::Storage, String> {
        let mut storage = Default::default();
        self.assimilate_storage(&mut storage)?;
        Ok(storage)
    }

    /// Assimilate the storage for this module into pre-existing overlays.
    fn assimilate_storage(&self, storage: &mut sp_runtime::Storage) -> Result<(), String> {
        sp_state_machine::BasicExternalities::execute_with_storage(storage, || {
            self.build();
            Ok(())
        })
    }
}
```

You can see this one being used as part of the [implementation of `GenesisConfig`in frame-system pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/e9b0facf70eeb08032cc7e83548c62f0b4a24bb1/frame/system/src/lib.rs#L676-L693).

```rust
/// Direct implementation of `GenesisBuild::assimilate_storage`.
///
/// Kept in order not to break dependency.
pub fn assimilate_storage<T: Config>(
    &self,
    storage: &mut sp_runtime::Storage,
) -> Result<(), String> {
    <Self as GenesisBuild<T>>::assimilate_storage(self, storage)
}
```